# Ubuntu live world clock app as desktop wallpaper or widget possible?

Tags: xubuntu, .desktop, clock, widgets

While I work in Germany, some of my colleagues work in India, some in Canada.

Is there a software to run in Ubuntu<sup>*</sup> and compatible environments so that the background screen displays sort of widget or live wallpaper with a configurable world clock?

If it matters, I have a 4K screen.

<sup>*</sup>I use Xubuntu 18.04 LTS

Comment: You haven't said which release of Xubuntu.  I've used `conky` in the past with XFCE but it was years ago (and included a number of timezones).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpConky  (*I did it back when Xubuntu was all GTK+2, it's now GTK+3 in later releases which may/may-not make a difference*)

Comment: @guiverc I can indeed install conky but what's the next step then?

Comment: That link contains pages about setting it up. When it was installed it had a default, I only modified that to become what I wanted (plus other useful eye candy; I primarily wanted temperature sensors, multiple timezone clocks was a bonus for me).  You can download many wonderful looking scripts, but I kept it 'light' and simple.  *If you wait you will likely get actual answers; but it'll be best coming from a recent or active user of conky, or other solution(s)*

Comment: I've tried a couple of samples for ~/.conky and /etc/conky/conky but with no effect after restarting, it keeps showing a htop like summary.

Comment: I suspect you're not running it, as I recall I had to make the program run when I wanted to use it (I set it up to autostart when I logged into desktop, but that wasn't a default).

Comment: it keeps showing a htop like summary

Comment: I may have put my config into `/etc/conky/conky.conf` for awhile, and had one somewhere in $HOME but it was too long ago for me to remember (4+ years ago). I wanted it primarily to monitor temperatures of a laptop. I may not have set it up correctly, but it filled my need giving clues as to my problem, I soon replaced my laptop fan & my problem went away, so did my primary reason for using conky.

Comment: @JusticeforMonica so I've created the given file path with given contents, run conky, same htop display

Comment: @JusticeforMonica FYI I've missed something important: if you run just ```conky``` it says ```conky: no personal or system-wide config file found, using builtin default```!
With the ```-c <CONFIGFILE>``` switch though I finally see the timezones widget! thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conky can be installed using `sudo apt install conky-all`.

The following is an example of conky running on Xubuntu 18.04.

[image: Conky showing times for four zones]

As background preparation, I created a blank panel at the top of the screen in addition to my actual panel at the bottom.

I then created `~/.config/conky.conf` as a plain text file with the following content:

```
-- vim: ts=4 sw=4 noet ai cindent syntax=lua
--[[
# Conky, a system monitor, based on torsmo
]]

conky.config = {
-- background = false,
default_color = '222222',
double_buffer = true,
draw_shades = false,
extra_newline = false,
font = 'Ubuntu Mono:bold:size=14',
gap_x = 1,
gap_y = 742,
minimum_width = 500,
own_window_class = 'Conky',
own_window_hints = 'undecorated,above,sticky,skip_pager',
own_window_transparent = yes,
own_window_colour = '454545',
own_window_argb_visual = true,
own_window_argb_value = 150,
own_window = true,
own_window_type = 'desktop',
short_units = true,
text_buffer_size = 256,
update_interval = 2.0,
use_spacer = 'right',
use_xft = true
}

conky.text = [[
${time %a %d %b} IST ${time %H:%M} UTC ${utime %H:%M} EST ${tztime America/New_York %H:%M} CAN_YU ${tztime Canada/Yukon %H:%M}
]]
-- info re. time zones in /usr/share/zoneinfo folder
```

I also added conky to Xubuntu's autostart menu using *Menu > Settings > Session and Startup > Application Autostart* as shown in the image. Using `--pause=30` delays conky from starting immediately by 30s: it is optional but I use it just as a precaution.

While I can use just `conky` for conky to run using my `~/.config/conky/conky.conf`, using `conky -c ~/.config/conky/conky.conf` has been found effective in [J. Doe's case](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1195057/ubuntu-live-world-clock-app-as-desktop-wallpaper-or-widget-possible/1195076?noredirect=1#comment2002396_1195076).

### Notes about the conky.conf

- single lines can be commented out using a leading `--`
- more than one contiguous lines can be commented out using an opening `--[[` and a closing `]]`
- `default_color = 222222` is the text color. Conky doesn't use `#222222`, just `222222`.
- `gap_x = 1` is the distance from the screen's left edge
- `gap_y = 742` positions the conky window pretty close to the top edge and will need to be adjusted according to your screen's dimensions
- `minimum_width` should be greater than the width occupied by your content
- `update_interval = 2.0` works for me
- the `conky.text` line specifies your content

  - `time %a %d %b` generates the day of the week, the date and the month of your locale as described in `man date`
  - the codes after IST, UTC, EST and CAN_YU provide the times for India, universal time, American East Coast time, and Canadian time (in Yukon). Information for other time zones is in the `/usr/share/zoneinfo` folder

(I can't make the conky background totally transparent!)

---

If you want to make changes to your `conky.conf`, open your terminal and run `conky`. As you edit and save your `conky.conf`, the conky window will disappear and reappear to reflect the changes.

Comment: strange enough I follow all the steps but the conky window keeps listing htop like summary. maybe I should post it as issue to their issue board. Thank you very much!

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 user  user 869 Dez 10 13:45 /home/user/.config/conky

Comment: @J.Doe and is this what you see? https://i.stack.imgur.com/HXkNW.png

Comment: yes, this is the exact layout which I see. I've chowned/chgrp'd the .config folder, same result unfortunately.

Comment: I've made chmod777 and emptied /etc/conky/ - still same result.

Comment: I've filed a bug to their GitHub - thank you very much!

Comment: Link to the GitHub issue: https://github.com/brndnmtthws/conky/issues/915

Comment: so with ```conky -c <CONFIGFILE>``` it runs finally, thank you! please add this to your answer.

Comment: I've added your input. Thanks!